# Problem with WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am trying to retrieve data from a page which first requires to log on, I am using a WebControl on a WinForms app, and when I try to log on an error pops up telling me "Object doesn't support this property or method" in a .js file at certain line, the method being called is

```
window.external.AutoCompleteSaveForm
```

which I have no Idea what it does.
the `webBrowser.ObjectForScripting` is set to `this`

I think the problem is the ObjectForScripting, but I don't really know which Object supports this method.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, you must provide an object for ObjectForScripting.  It could be anything, as long as it has the [ComVisible(true)] attribute so it is callable from COM code.  To keep the script happy, you must provide a public AutoCompleteSaveForm(object) method.  No need to do anything.  The [MSDN library article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535246%28VS.85%29.aspx) has a decent example.